# error importing backend from keras over tensorflow

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow, keras

After installing cuda 9, cudnn 7, tensorflow and keras, keras cannot find the backend.  Running on Ubuntu.
Any idea what to do?

Thanks!

Here are some outputs that may help find the problem:

1)

> $ python3
>
> ```
> Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Apr 29 2018,
> ```
>
> 16:14:56) 
>       [GCC 7.2.0] on linux
>       Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>
> ```
> import keras
>
> from keras import backend as K
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'backend'
> ```

2)

> ~/.keras$ more keras.json

{

> ```
> "epsilon": 1e-07, 
> "floatx": "float32", 
> "image_data_format": "channels_last", 
> "backend": "tensorflow" }
> ```

3)

```
pip list
Package                            Version  
---------------------------------- ---------
absl-py                            0.2.2    
alabaster                          0.7.10   
anaconda-client                    1.6.14   
anaconda-navigator                 1.7.0    
anaconda-project                   0.8.2    
asn1crypto                         0.24.0   
astor                              0.6.2    
astroid                            1.6.3    
astropy                            3.0.2    
attrs                              18.1.0   
Babel                              2.5.3    
backcall                           0.1.0    
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size 1.0.0    
beautifulsoup4                     4.6.0    
bitarray                           0.8.1    
bkcharts                           0.2      
blaze                              0.11.3   
bleach                             1.5.0    
bokeh                              0.12.16  
boto                               2.48.0   
Bottleneck                         1.2.1    
certifi                            2018.4.16
cffi                               1.11.5   
chardet                            3.0.4    
click                              6.7      
cloudpickle                        0.5.3    
clyent                             1.2.2    
colorama                           0.3.9    
conda                              4.5.5    
conda-build                        3.4.1    
conda-verify                       2.0.0    
contextlib2                        0.5.5    
cryptography                       2.2.2    
cycler                             0.10.0   
Cython                             0.28.2   
cytoolz                            0.9.0.1  
dask                               0.18.1   
datashape                          0.5.4    
decorator                          4.3.0    
distributed                        1.21.8   
docutils                           0.14     
entrypoints                        0.2.3    
et-xmlfile                         1.0.1    
fastcache                          1.0.2    
filelock                           3.0.4    
Flask                              1.0.2    
Flask-Cors                         3.0.4    
gast                               0.2.0    
gevent                             1.3.0    
gitdb2                             2.0.3    
GitPython                          2.1.9    
glob2                              0.6      
gmpy2                              2.0.8    
greenlet                           0.4.13   
grpcio                             1.12.1   
h5py                               2.7.1    
heapdict                           1.0.0    
html5lib                           0.9999999
idna                               2.6      
imageio                            2.3.0    
imagesize                          1.0.0    
ipykernel                          4.8.2    
ipython                            6.4.0    
ipython-genutils                   0.2.0    
ipywidgets                         7.2.1    
isort                              4.3.4    
itsdangerous                       0.24     
jdcal                              1.4      
jedi                               0.12.0   
Jinja2                             2.10     
jsonschema                         2.6.0    
jupyter                            1.0.0    
jupyter-client                     5.2.3    
jupyter-console                    5.2.0    
jupyter-core                       4.4.0    
jupyterlab                         0.32.1   
jupyterlab-launcher                0.10.5   
Keras                              2.2.0    
Keras-Applications                 1.0.2    
Keras-Preprocessing                1.0.1    
kiwisolver                         1.0.1    
lazy-object-proxy                  1.3.1    
llvmlite                           0.23.1   
locket                             0.2.0    
lxml                               4.2.1    
Markdown                           2.6.11   
MarkupSafe                         1.0      
matplotlib                         2.2.2    
mccabe                             0.6.1    
missinglink-kernel                 0.5028   
missinglink-sdk                    0.5028   
mistune                            0.8.3    
mkl-fft                            1.0.0    
mkl-random                         1.0.1    
more-itertools                     4.1.0    
mpmath                             1.0.0    
msgpack                            0.5.6    
msgpack-python                     0.5.6    
multipledispatch                   0.5.0    
navigator-updater                  0.1.0    
nbconvert                          5.3.1    
nbformat                           4.4.0    
networkx                           2.1      
nltk                               3.3      
nose                               1.3.7    
notebook                           5.5.0    
numba                              0.38.0   
numexpr                            2.6.5    
numpy                              1.14.3   
numpydoc                           0.8.0    
odo                                0.5.1    
olefile                            0.45.1   
opencv-python                      3.4.1.15 
openpyxl                           2.5.3    
packaging                          17.1     
pandas                             0.23.3   
pandocfilters                      1.4.2    
parso                              0.2.0    
partd                              0.3.8    
path.py                            11.0.1   
pathlib2                           2.3.2    
patsy                              0.5.0    
pep8                               1.7.1    
pexpect                            4.5.0    
pickleshare                        0.7.4    
Pillow                             5.1.0    
pip                                10.0.1   
pkginfo                            1.4.2    
pluggy                             0.6.0    
ply                                3.11     
prompt-toolkit                     1.0.15   
protobuf                           3.5.2    
psutil                             5.4.5    
ptyprocess                         0.5.2    
py                                 1.5.3    
pycodestyle                        2.4.0    
pycosat                            0.6.3    
pycparser                          2.18     
pycrypto                           2.6.1    
pycurl                             7.43.0.1 
pyflakes                           1.6.0    
Pygments                           2.2.0    
pylint                             1.8.4    
pyodbc                             4.0.23   
pyOpenSSL                          18.0.0   
pyparsing                          2.2.0    
PySocks                            1.6.8    
pytest                             3.5.1    
pytest-arraydiff                   0.2      
pytest-astropy                     0.3.0    
pytest-doctestplus                 0.1.3    
pytest-openfiles                   0.3.0    
pytest-remotedata                  0.2.1    
python-dateutil                    2.7.3    
pytz                               2018.4   
PyWavelets                         0.5.2    
PyYAML                             3.12     
pyzmq                              17.0.0   
QtAwesome                          0.4.4    
qtconsole                          4.3.1    
QtPy                               1.4.1    
requests                           2.18.4   
retrying                           1.3.3    
rope                               0.10.7   
ruamel-yaml                        0.15.35  
scikit-image                       0.13.1   
scikit-learn                       0.19.1   
scipy                              1.1.0    
seaborn                            0.8.1    
Send2Trash                         1.5.0    
setuptools                         39.1.0   
simplegeneric                      0.8.1    
singledispatch                     3.4.0.3  
six                                1.11.0   
smmap2                             2.0.3    
snowballstemmer                    1.2.1    
sortedcollections                  0.6.1    
sortedcontainers                   1.5.10   
Sphinx                             1.7.4    
sphinxcontrib-websupport           1.0.1    
spyder                             3.2.8    
SQLAlchemy                         1.2.7    
statsmodels                        0.9.0    
style                              1.1.0    
sympy                              1.1.1    
tables                             3.4.3    
tblib                              1.3.2    
tensorboard                        1.8.0    
tensorflow                         1.8.0    
tensorflow-gpu                     1.8.0    
termcolor                          1.1.0    
terminado                          0.8.1    
testpath                           0.3.1    
toolz                              0.9.0    
tornado                            5.0.2    
traitlets                          4.3.2    
typing                             3.6.4    
unicodecsv                         0.14.1   
update                             0.0.1    
urllib3                            1.22     
wcwidth                            0.1.7    
webencodings                       0.5.1    
Werkzeug                           0.14.1   
wheel                              0.31.1   
widgetsnbextension                 3.2.1    
wrapt                              1.10.11  
xlrd                               1.1.0    
XlsxWriter                         1.0.4    
xlwt                               1.3.0    
zict                               0.1.3
```

Comment: Can you print 'sys.path' before the failing import and verify that the expected files are indeed present in expected places. Maybe the installation did not finish successfully. Also, recent versions of tensorflow have keras API included (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras). So, you should be able to just import keras from tensorflow.